# Software for stacking Arduino Shields

Tags: arduino

I have been messing with Seeed [Ethernet](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Ethernet_Shield_V1.0), [SD](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/SD_Card_Shield_V3.0), and a [TFT](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/2.8%27%27_TFT_Touch_Shield_V1.0) Shields in learning how to use Arduino. However, I have found that I cannot use these shields together because all three of them use Pin 10 for their SS pin.

Is there any way to programmatically change SS pins for any Arduino shield?

I know that the SD library has SD.begin(), but even when I set the pin to an unused pin, the shields do not work together. I know that there is a SPI library that comes with the Arduino softwrare, but `SPI.begin(slaveSelectPin)` is only on Arduino Due, and I have an Arduino Uno.

I found the [Go-Between Shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11002), but looking at the user guide, I would still have to change my code to use other pins on the Arduino (unless Im reading it wrong), so why not skip it entirely, and make the changes on the shields I already have.

Would this be better on electricalengineering?

Comment: Have a look here: http://mosquino.googlecode.com/hg-history/5ceb2c9af1bfdc97e702e384bc702810ef9e707f/libraries/sdfatlib-mosquino/readme.txt I have not tried it myself but should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to programmatically change SS pins for any Arduino
>   shield?

No. The pin is hardwired on the shield. You can use different pins on your arduino as SS pins, but they will be connected to the "same" pin on the boards. For this you wouldn't be able to stack the shields and would have to write the SPI code in software.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the actual shields and their revision, it might indeed be possible to hack a pin here and there to map SS to a different pin on the Arduino.

After this remapping you will have to make similar adjustment to the libraries that expect SS to be on pin-10. Often it's an parameter to a constructor and therefore quite easy.

Soldering iron and tweezers!

Comment: The linked shields are the ones I have

Comment: With the two first ones it certainly looks doable. But the display seems to be using almost every pin available on a small Arduino, not sure if that one can coexists with much. Since you are asking in the first place I'm super confident that I should recommend you to hack your shields, there is a chance to ruin them in the process. If you are hellbent on doing it, **heat pin-10 on the shield until it melts its way out of bard and plastic, then connect a jumper from the hole to your new SS pin**.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the interface on the TFT shield is not SPI.  It's a little confusing as the driver chip does support SPI but this is not the mode which the shield is configured to use.

See section 6.2 in the [ST7781R driver chip datasheet](http://garden.seeedstudio.com/images/4/4e/ST7781R_datasheet.pdf).

You might be able to hack the TFT shield so that it uses SPI, but that is a project in itself.

Try using the ethernet and SD shields, can you get them to work together, they should without any problem (once you've resolved the SS problem which is just a case of snipping the pin on the top shield and soldering a breadboard wire from the desired pin on the arduino then plugging the other end in top shield pin 10).

I'm not sure if there's an SPI version of the TFT shield, you might be able to return to the store in exchange for the right one.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to change the pins in software. The pins are determined by each shields hardware. Unless you modify the hardware there is no way to deal with this.

However if you stack so many shields you should consider if the Arduino is still the proper platform. There are many other small systems out there (e.g. Raspi) that have significantly more horse power and that offer a USB Bus for conncting devices.

IMHO the Arduino is good for low level pin control but not for driving peripherals. I would suggest a design where a Raspi or similar does most of the work, especially driving the displays and the SD card and the Arduino takes care of the low level PIN IO.

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino does fine for driving peripherals, but you do have to get creative with pin remapping. There's a shield database that lists the pin requirements of each shield, and pulling a pin and adding a jumper (and remapping in the code or library) will work for any interference issues. I've done some very complicated projects, and see no need for a RPi.

http://www.shieldlist.org